# Switching Power Supply Crowbar

Tags: switching, linear

In our lab we have a large fan on an instrument which works fine on a linear power supply but on a switching power supply the supply crowbar even when it's current limit is well above the operating current. I suspect a large inrush current. The linear PS has a similar current limit. How can I prevent the crowbar?

Comment: A crowbar circuit is one that intentionally shorts two lines when too much voltage is present in order to blow a fuse or trigger interrupts while preventing the overvoltage from reaching a level that can do damage.  If your protection device is blowing because of inrush current, that's a separate problem.  You need to better explain what is happening with the supply, as well as the specs of the supply and the motor in question.

Comment: Is it a DC fan, not brushless? You likely need a soft start circuit on the fan. Current on a fan with a heavy load can pull locked rotor current for a very long time. Check the spin up speed of the fan when connected to the linear supply.

Comment: Please clarify: is it a crowbar or a foldback? a crowbar act on overvoltage, a foldback on overcurrent. They are very different things

Comment: You can also try attaching a large capacitor to the supply prior to attaching the fan. Maybe the capacitor will hold up the voltage long enough to avoid folding back current (I assume it is a foldback rather than a crowbar).

Comment: I assumed the crowbar was caused by a large in rush current. The problem is the crowbar. Did not mean to mislead. Sorry.